# How to select buttons in tvOS menu for SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3, tvos

I am extending my iOS game for tvOS. Most of the game controls are handled by `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`. All my select buttons are handled in the following way:

```
 if button1.contains(location){
    let gameplayScene = GamePlayScene(size: self.size)
    self.view?.presentScene(gameplayScene)
 }
if button2.contains(location){
    let settingsScene  = SettingsScene(size: self.size)
    self.view?.presentScene(settingsScene)
 }
if button3.contains(location){
    let helpScene = HelpScene(size: self.size)
    self.view?.presentScene(helpScene)
 }
```

for an image below:

[image]

How can I appropriately highlight and select each one of these buttons in tvOS using the AppleTV remote?

Comment: I will be very grateful if someone could help me

Comment: Are the buttons regular UIButtons or something else?

Comment: @Stefan I used `SKSpriteNode`s for the buttons

Comment: shouldn't you be doing: `if touch.location.contains(node: button1)` etc inside your scene's touchesBegan?

Comment: @Fluidity Actually I didn't include the full touchesBegan code. I have `let location = touch.location(in: self)` and it's working perfectly for iOS. I am trying to find a way to implement this for AppleTV remote.

Comment: @Hilarious404 did you watch any of the WWDC videos for apple TV? Or the (lackluster) documentation? They also have some example projects you can download on their website. I know they cover how to do this, I just haven't tried coding it yet myself.

Comment: just so we are on the same page, you *do* know how to do this easily for iOS right? It's just the tvOS you are struggling with? Or are you new to SK in general?

Comment: @Fluidity Yes, I have implemented this in iOS and its working perfectly. I just need some help with tvOS